# Getting Logstash web to work in unicast environment: ClusterBlockException

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to run Logstash and Elasticsearch on a Windows machine.

The ElasticSearch server is set to use unicast (couldn't get multicast working).

The Logstash agent uses the "elasticsearch_http" output plugin because I couldn't get the regular "elasticsearch" plugin to talk to Elasticsearch.

So, my issue now is I can't figure out how to set the command-line parameter for the Logstash web backend.  I've tried various settings:

```
java ... -- web -- log c:/logstash/logstash_webui.log --backend elasticsearch:///?local

java ... -- web -- log c:/logstash/logstash_webui.log --backend elasticsearch://localhost

java ... -- web -- log c:/logstash/logstash_webui.log --backend elasticsearch://localhost/

java ... -- web -- log c:/logstash/logstash_webui.log --backend elasticsearch://localhost:9300

java ... -- web -- log c:/logstash/logstash_webui.log --backend elasticsearch://localhost:9300/

java ... -- web -- log c:/logstash/logstash_webui.log --backend "elasticsearch://localhost:9300/"
```

But I keep getting this error in the browser when trying to search:

```
blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];[SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/2/no master];
```

And I see this error in the logstash_webui.log file:

```
Java::OrgElasticsearchClusterBlock::ClusterBlockException - blocked by [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];[SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/2/no master];
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So sorry you're having these issues, we're working on making it easier for folks on windows.

I havn't used the web app packaged with LogStash in quite a while, and I'm not sure if its even maintained. This is because there is a much better alternative. [Kibana](http://kibana.org/) is a ruby app built by [rashidkpc](https://twitter.com/rashidkpc) that does a great job of digging through your logs indexed in elasticsearch.

You can checkout a demo [here](http://demo.logstash.net/), though I'm not sure if there is any data in it.